# Who do I consult/hire for porch redesign?

Tags: porch

I'm in need of redesign of both porch and a landscape adjacent to it, including drainage. Who do I consult or hire for this kind of job (e.g. Engineer, Architect, Landscaper, General Contractor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know what you want and the changes are mostly cosmetic, a GC should be able to do it all.

If the changes are substantial, you need somebody to help you figure out what you want, and there are serious considerations regarding drainage, then you need an engineer to do a site plan, an architect to draw the porch plans, and a GC to do the job. Some GCs might employ engineers and/or architects in-house. The GC will hire the excavating company to do the site work, which includes the drainage work, and depending on your contract, the landscaper.

Comment: The GC may even have their own in-house designers.

Comment: And if not, a GC can subcontract parts of the job they don't have the skills or licenses for. Alternative is to play that role yourself, coordinating however many services are necessary; more hassle but _may_ be cheaper if you have the skills to do that and/or to do some of the subtasks yourself.